# code not going to the next sheet , just changes only active sheet

Tags: vba, excel

I am currently writing a simple macro (see below). I intend for the macro to change all of the worksheets in my workbook. however, it only changes the cells in the active sheet that I am on, i have to manually move to the next sheet and run the macro to change the cell currently but its being tedious, especially when I have about 125 worksheets to update.

```
Sub worksheetloop()

Dim sh As Worksheet

With ThisWorkbook    
    For Each sh In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets    
        Range("$F$5") = "toothwidth" ' Key contact
        Range("$F$8") = "x,y,z" ' Core team
        Range("$J$5") = "bleh" 'date
        Range("$L$5") = "9/12/" 'Updated
        Range("$M$5") = "A" ' Revision Date                              
    Next sh    
End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to qualify the `Range` you use with `sh` worksheet object inside your `For Each sh In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets` loop.

Try the code below:

```
Dim sh As Worksheet

For Each sh In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
    With sh
        .Range("$F$5") = "toothwidth" ' Key contact
        .Range("$F$8") = "x,y,z" ' Core team
        .Range("$J$5") = "bleh" 'date
        .Range("$L$5") = "9/12/" 'Updated
        .Range("$M$5") = "A" ' Revision Date\
    End With
Next sh
```

Comment: that worked, but can you clarify why? i dont understand what you mean by qualify.

Comment: @SergioOropeza in your code you use `Range("$F$5") = "toothwidth"`, which means looking for this Range in `ActiveSheet`. If you ass `sh.Range("$F$5") = "toothwidth"` , it means qualify your range with `sh` worksheet.

Comment: In a nutshell, your `With` statement is useless with `Range`, you might have well left that line out. When you use `.Range` that links your statement to the `With sh` statement you made earlier in the code.

Comment: here is a "real world" example. .....  you are teaching a school class. ..... you hand three books to each student ... math book, history book and science book .... you tell the class "open one of the books"  .... so now, some of the students will open the math book, and some will open the history book and some will open the science book. .... now say "turn to page 34"   ... that is like `Range("$F$5")`  ...... now fully qualify the page "turn to math book, page 34"   ..... that is similar to this `worksheets("sheet1").Range("$F$5")`

Comment: @SergioOropeza if your probelm is solved, please mark this as "ANSWER", by clicking the gray check-mark on the left side of my answer